# Find visually similar images and bulk select and delete

Tags: windows, images, duplicate-files

Let me give you some context. I gave a friend my camera and he was using it in Burst mode so it took 4-5 images of the same person/thing.

I want to select only 1 or the similar 4-5 images. There are 1000s of such photos.

I am using Windows. How can automate this? Or bulk process the images?

Do suggest both paid and freeware options.

Thanks